# Getting image build error when triggering dockerhub repository, but builds locally without problems

Tags: typescript, docker, vue.js, dockerhub

I've started a new Vue project, builded by the Vue CLI. I want to use docker, and I'm having no problems building the image locally on my machine. The issue happens when I push my code to my repository, which then triggers a build in dockerhub. Dockerhub runs well untill step 7/9, where it is supposed to run npm build. The build fails with the following error:

```
This relative module was not found:
    * ./src/main.ts in multi ./src/main.ts ERROR Build failed with errors.
```

Full error log below:

```
Building for production... Starting type checking and linting service... Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit ERROR Failed to compile with 1 errors4:57:48 PM This relative module was not found:
* ./src/main.ts in multi ./src/main.ts ERROR Build failed with errors. npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 build script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2019-04-04T16_57_48_179Z-debug.log Removing intermediate container 993eab310ea3 The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The questions I'm left with from this is:

1. What does the line "* ./src/main.ts in multi ./src/main.ts" mean?
2. And how do I fix this?

I tried to run the image build on google cloud as well, just to see if there was a problem with the coorporation between me and dockerhub, but google returned with the same error.

```
//Dockerfile
FROM node:lts-alpine

# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN npm install -g http-server

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /src

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .

# build app for production with minification
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]


//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./built/",
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}


//main.ts
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

[Image of my Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh5L1.png)

I hope I've included the right information, for helping you, helping me.

Comment: Sometimes these kind of errors are due to case sensitivity of filename references. So it's worth double checking. If your local filesystem handles file references in a case insensitive way then it may build fine.